# Adicionar e remover class em uma lista de divs dinâmicas

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou com a seguinte estrutura de divs que foram criadas dinamicamente no formato de uma timeline:

```
<!-- Timelime example  -->
      <div class="container">
        <?php foreach ($manager->selectAllGeneric('postagem') as $item) : ?>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="timeline">
                <div class="time-label">

                  <span style="background-color: #49C3B1; color: #fff;">
                    <?php setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
                    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
                    echo utf8_encode(strftime('%d de %B', strtotime($item['dt_criacao']))); ?>
                  </span>
                </div>

                <div>
                  <img class="direct-chat-img" src="dist/img/user3-128x128.jpg" alt="Message User Image">
                  <div class="timeline-item">

                    <span class="time"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i> <?= date('H:i:s', strtotime($item['dt_criacao'])); ?></span>

                    <?php if ($item['user_alteracao'] != '') : ?>
                      <span class="time">alterado por <?= $item['user_alteracao']; ?> às
                        <?= date('H:i:s', strtotime($item['dt_alteracao'])); ?>
                      </span>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <h3 class="timeline-header"><a href="#"><?= $item['user_criacao']; ?></a><br><?= $item['ds_titulo']; ?></h3>

                    <div class="timeline-body">
                      <div id="post" class="img-recolhido">    
                        <?= $item['ds_post']; ?>
                      </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="timeline-footer">
                      <a id="mais" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mais" name="id_post">Ver mais</a>
                      <a id="menos" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm menos" name="id_post">Ver menos</a>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde o corpo da div definida em:

```
<div class="timeline-body">
    <div id="post" class="img-recolhido">
        <?= $item['ds_post']; ?>
</div>
```

Contém a seguinte class="img-recolhida"

```
.img-recolhida {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Definindo o tamanho para todas divs recolhidas, e ao clicar em ver mais via javascript eu removo e adiciono a class="img-total"

```
.img-total {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
}
```

Para expandir a div e mostrar o conteúdo completo!

Função javascritpt:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j('.mais').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let post = document.getElementById('post');
    post.classList.remove('img-recolhido');
    post.classList.add('img-total');

    $j('.mais').hide();
    $j('.menos').show();

});

$j('.menos').on('click', function(event) {

    $j('.menos').hide();
    $j('.mais').show();

    let post = document.getElementById('post');
    post.classList.remove('img-total');
    post.classList.add('img-recolhido');
});

$j(document).ready(function() {

    $j('.menos').hide();
});
```

Até aí tudo bem, se fosse apenas um item! Mas como a lista de divs é dinâmica a função funciona apenas para a primeira div! Se eu acionar o botão ver mais da segunda div, a ação é disparada na primeira div!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como poderia disparar a ação apenas na div selecionada se as divs tem o mesmo id="post"!?

Comment: Eu não entendi muito, como assim as divs tem o mesmo `id`? Esse atributo **deve** ser único no seu html. Um jeito de fazer isso é passando o mesmo atributo tanto para a div, quanto para o botão, sem repeti-los, e na hora de clicar, validar em a partir disso. Eu usaria o `id` da postagem. Daí você consegue mostrar somente a imagem que tiver o msm id do botão clicado

Comment: @andre_luiss sim eu poderia passar o id da postagem assim id='<?php $item['id_post'] ?>' mas como eu vou pegar ele no javascript  let post = document.getElementById('???');

Comment: Vou adicionar uma resposta com um código de exemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma simples de fazer isso é passando o mesmo atributo **único** para o elemento que você vai interagir, e o elemento que você irá manipular. No seu caso, eu usaria o `id` da postagem.

Vi que você tá usando jQuery, então esse exemplo, deve funcionar para sua necessidade:

```js
$('.show').click(function() {
  let id = $(this).attr('data-show-card') // recupera o id do elemento

  $(`[data-texto=${id}]`).show() // pega o elemento com o id desejado
  $(`[data-hide-card=${id}]`).show()

  $(this).hide()
})

$('.close').click(function() {
  let id = $(this).attr('data-hide-card') // recupera o id do elemento

  $(`[data-texto=${id}]`).hide() // pega o elemento com o id desejado
  $(`[data-show-card=${id}]`).show()

  $(this).hide()
})
```

```css
.card {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.card .text {
  display: none;
}

.close {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <p data-texto="1" class="text">Esse texto te deixa feliz!</p>
  <button data-show-card="1" class="show">Ver Texto</button>
  <button data-hide-card="1" class="close">Esconder Texto</button>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <p data-texto="2" class="text">Esse texto te deixa feliz no card 2 haha!</p>
  <button data-show-card="2" class="show" >Ver Texto</button>
  <button data-hide-card="2" class="close">Esconder Texto</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```